# Is it sinful for priests or/and those in state of religion to hug women?

Tags: catholicism, morality, priesthood

**Question.**

Is it sinful for priests or/and those in state of religion (eg. Franciscans, Dominicans, etc.) to hug women (of course, we are not speaking of hugging mother, sister or something like that)?

**Argument against.**

We can see this [happen publicly on the show The Voice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpaQYSd75Ak&t=7m44s) (about 7 minutes and 45 seconds in the video). Also, I see many examples in the youth groups where the priest becomes (very) friendly with the youth. So, obviously those who have authority are seen to do such things and I have seen no one to reproach them; so it seems that they are not doing anything evil.

**Argument for.**

It would seem that all hugging between male and female (which are not husband or wife or are family) is sinful (so for a priest or religious it is also a sin). For it is mentioned as a sin in the [Eisenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Eisengrein) [*Confessionale* p.180](https://books.google.hr/books?id=51LYJIbEA5EC&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=vel%20tetigit%20mulierem&source=bl&ots=JsXkbRM7Py&sig=ACfU3U3bn9G3dy50d6pTi1lL3nNcah1o4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB4uKyyNPjAhUumIsKHfwlDF8Q6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> qui deliberate exosculatus aut complexus fuit vel tetigit mulierem
>   (who deliberately kissed, hugged or touched woman)

Comment: The most likely answer is that it depends on the rules of their order. And it is entirely possible that the rules are different for when someone hugs you (as shown in the video) compared with when you hug someone.

Comment: @DJClayworth There's an order that mentions hugging women in its rule?

Comment: @Geremia perhaps not in any rules for religious, I know some traditional religious communities where it is their tradition not to hug or handshake anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be:

- Scandal

  - So as to avoid scandal, [can. 667](http://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib2-cann607-709_en.html#CHAPTER_IV.) on [enclosure](https://archive.org/details/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary/page/n1142) prohibits certain people from entering cloisters.
  - [Can. 667](http://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib2-cann607-709_en.html#CHAPTER_IV.) §4 governs how semi-cloistered nuns (i.e., those with episcopal enclosure) can be outside their convents:

    > §4. **For a just cause, a diocesan bishop has the faculty** of entering the cloister of monasteries of nuns which are in his diocese and, for a grave cause and with the consent of the superior, **of permitting** others to be admitted to the cloister and the **nuns to leave** it [**their cloister**] **for a truly necessary period of time**.

    Contemplatives, who are under papal enclosure, need the Pope's permission.
- Lust

  - If the hugs are done for lustful motives (cf. [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 154 a. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A4THEP1))
- Over-familiarity

  - [*Super Io.*, cap. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/John4.htm) l. 6.:  "*nimia familiaritas, reverentiam minuit, et contemptum parit*" ("over-familiarity diminishes reverence and breeds contempt")
- [Sacrilege](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36218)

  - Just like a chalice, consecrated to hold the Precious Blood, used for a profane purpose (such as for drinking water) would be sacrilege, so, too, is "laying violent* hands on clerics or religious of either sex" or "the commission of acts of unchastity by or with a person bound by the public vow of chastity" sacrilege.
    <sub>*The hugging you show in your YouTube video appears violent, forced upon her.</sub>

Also, regarding your link to the *The Voice* show, listen to this sermon: "[Sister Cristina & the Current Church Crisis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcjgL-n8B2I)."

Comment: @Thom St. Paul says ([1 Cor. 7:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=7&l=1-#x)): "It is good \[or 'a beautiful thing,' [καλόν](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%8C%CE%BD) = beautiful\] for a man not to touch a woman."

Comment: @Thom Cf. [St. Thomas's commentary on 1 Cor. 7:1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/SS1Cor.htm#71). {Also, contrary to some Protestant exegetes, St. Paul asserts (not merely relays or repeats what the Corinthians wrote to him) that "It is good for a man not to touch a woman."}

Comment: Even Paul would agree that "It is good to do this" is not the same as "It is a sin not to do this".

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, if he thought it is always sinful to touch a woman, he would be condemning marriage (or at least its use) and contradicting himself (e.g., [v. 3](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=7&l=3-#x)).

Comment: @Geremia I think in context, St. Paul means "to be sexual with any woman:" "Now concerning the things you wrote to me:

It is best that a man not touch a woman. Nevertherless, to avoid sins of a sexual nature, let every man have his own wife, and every woman her own husband.

Let the husband render to the wife that which is due her, and the wife likewise to the husband. The wife has no right over her own body, but the husband: and likewise also the husband has no right over his own body, but the wife. ...

Comment: "...Do not deprive one another, unless it be for an agreed period of time, to allow yourselves time for fasting and prayer: and afterwards be once again united, so that Satan does not tempt you in your weakness.

I say this by way of concession, and not by way of command." I will note that clearly if this means sexual union, the concession is marriage: it's always a sin to commit *porneia* (sexual sin).

Comment: @SolaGratia [Fr. Allo, O.P.'s commentary](https://archive.org/details/MN41377ucmf_4/page/n266): «[άπτεσθαι](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%AC%CF%80%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B1%CE%B9#lexicon) can mean "to touch," "be attached to," "enter into contact with," "have intimate relations with;" here it is a matter of any relation that does not allow for complete continence.»

Comment: @SolaGratia "_the concession is marriage: it's always a sin to commit_ porneia _(sexual sin)._" Yes, St. Paul discusses that in the previous chapter, [6:12](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=6&l=12-#x)ff.

Comment: It's hard to say with absolute certainty, I think, inasmuch as "touch" somewhat ambiguous here.

Comment: @SolaGratia The same verb ([ἅπτω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CE%AC%CF%80%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%85&la=greek#lexicon)) is used in [John 20:17](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=20&l=17-#x), too, where He tells St. Mary Magdalene "Do not touch me: for I am not yet ascended to my Father." Clearly He's using the term in wide sense there, not a purely sexual sense.

Comment: Sorry to say, but papal enclosures do not need the permission of the Pope to leave the convent or have other permitted to enter. Depending on  circumstances the superior, superior and the council or the local bishop normally suffices. See here: [VERBI SPONSA](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccscrlife/documents/rc_con_ccscrlife_doc_13051999_verbi-sponsa_en.html)

Comment: @KenGraham The superior can only allow nuns to leave the enclosure in "cases involving the health of the nuns, the care of infirm nuns, the exercise of civil rights [e.g., voting] and needs of the monastery which cannot otherwise be provided for."

Comment: “For other just and grave reasons the Superior, with the consent of her Council or the conventual Chapter, and in accordance with the norms contained in the Constitutions, can authorize a departure for whatever time is needed, not however beyond one week. If the stay outside the monastery has to be further extended, up to three months, the Superior will seek the authorization of the Diocesan Bishop, (67) or the regular Superior if there is one. Should the absence exceed three months, other than in cases of health care, permission must be obtained from the Holy See.”

Comment: @Geremia I was not suggesting that this was its meaning everywhere, just as I would not say "know" means "to be sexually intimate with" outside "Adam knew his wife," "I know not man" etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it sinful for priests or/and those in state of religion to hug women?**

**It is not intrinsically sinful for priests or religious to hug or be hugged by members of the opposite sex.** If it were there would be well founded guidelines to be found in every diocese, seminary, house of formation, etc etc.

One can find on YouTube popes being hugged by women too.

That stated, this subject matter merits a caveat.

Although it may not be intrinsically sinful for a priest to hug a woman, it should something rarely done. More often than not, it is the priest who is the recipient of this gesture.

Prudence dictates that in order not to be tempted in such circumstances, priests should strive to avoid such occasions where they can be tempted by the Devil  into committing sin!

This whole question reminds me of the story found in the Dialogues of St. Gregory the Great about how the demon tempted a bishop to sin against chastity by simply patting the back of a nun. This particular episode as recounted by Pope St. Gregory the Great would make a great Halloween story:

[Chapter Seven: of Andrew, Bishop of Funda.](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/gregory_03_dialogues_book3.htm#C7)

I know, though experience that there exists Benedictine cloistered nuns that according to their tradition will not hug anyone, they will not even shake hands with someone.

On the other end of the spectrum, I know of cloistered Poor Clare religious that will hug women visitors and shake hands with the men.

Hugs given to or received by priests or consecrated religious is not intrinsically sinful, but could be the occasion towards sin. Thus it should be frowned on, to say the least.

As side note, I have noticed that married deacons are very generous in this regards in our diocese.

Comment: @Thom No, but it something that needs to be avoided.

Comment: @KenGraham St. Gregory the Great seems to be speaking of the [_virgines subintroductæ_](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/virgines-subintroductae) (female servants surreptitiously brought into bishops' homes), a practice the Church has condemned.

Comment: @Thom cf. this article on the _subintroductæ_: Elizabeth A. Clark, “[John Chrysostom and the _Subintroductae_](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/2X4J7PED/Clark%20-%201977%20-%20John%20Chrysostom%20and%20the%20Subintroductae.pdf),” _Church History_ 46, no. 2 (June 1977): 171–85.

Comment: It all starts innocently  enough (just one touch): “Bishop Andrew, concerning that Nun which he kept in his palace: whereunto whiles the master devil gave attentive ear, considering with himself what a notable gain it would be, to undo the soul of so holy a man; the former devil went on with his tale, **and said that the very evening before he assaulted him so mightily, that he drew him so far forth, that he did merrily strike the said Nun upon the back. ”** Read the story.